# How can I update Order records in SQL based on OrderItem record values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update a flag value in my Orders table, but only if at least one of the OrderItems connected to that Orders record by OrderID, in my OrderItems table, are a certain state.

Scenario 1: All 3 OrderItems connected to an Order are 'Cancelled' - **do not update Orders flag**

Scenario 2: At least one of the OrderItems connected to an Order are NOT 'Cancelled' - **update the Orders flag**

Scenario 3: None of the OrderItems connected to an Order are 'Cancelled' - **update the Orders flag**

How can this be done - and efficiently?

Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE o
SET   o.Flag = true
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi ON oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE o.Flag = false
AND oi.State <> 'Cancelled'
```

The INNER JOIN will potentially return multiple records from OrderItems. Not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: Some sample data with expected results would be helpful.

Comment: I added what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, required statement should update rows from `dbo.Orders` table only for scenario 2 and 3.

1) If - for S2 and S3 - you have to update orders with the same flag the one solution is following UPDATE:

```
UPDATE o
SET Flag = 1 -- common flag for S2 and S3
FROM dbo.Orders o
WHEER EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderItems oi
    WHERE oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
    -- Uncomment if oi.Status allows NULLs
    AND (/*oi.Status IS NULL OR*/ oi.Status <> 'Cancelled')
)
```

2) Buf if you have to update to diff. flags then I would use following statement

```
UPDATE o
SET Flag = 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderItems oi2 WHERE oi2.OrderID = o.OrderID AND oi2.Status = 'Cancelled')
        THEN 2 -- Status for second scenario
        ELSE 3 -- Status for third scenario
    END
FROM dbo.Orders o
WHEER EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderItems oi
    WHERE oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
    -- Uncomment if oi.Status allows NULLs
    AND (/*oi.Status IS NULL OR*/ oi.Status <> 'Cancelled')
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Scenario 1 was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
create table orders
(
    orderID int,
    orderName varchar(50),
    orderDate datetime,
    isValidOrderFlag bit
)

create table orderdetail
(
    orderdetailID int,
    orderID int,
    productName varchar(100),
    productCost numeric(9,2),
    quantity int,
    isCancelled bit
)

insert into orders values (1234, 'Bob Garvey', GETDATE() - 5, 0);
insert into orders values (1235, 'Susan  Hamilton', GETDATE() - 5, 0);
insert into orders values (1236, 'Bob Garvey', GETDATE() - 5, 0);
insert into orders values (1237, 'Sarah Smith', GETDATE() - 4, 0);

-- all 3 order items are cancelled do not update orders flag
insert into orderdetail values (10000, 1234, 'thing1', 9.95, 10, 1);
insert into orderdetail values (10001, 1234, 'thing2', 5.99, 10, 1);
insert into orderdetail values (10002, 1234, 'thing3', 1.99, 1, 1);

-- at least one order is cancelled update orders flag
insert into orderdetail values (10000, 1235, 'thing1', 9.95, 10, 1);
insert into orderdetail values (10001, 1235, 'thing2', 5.99, 10, 0);
insert into orderdetail values (10002, 1235, 'thing3', 1.99, 1, 0);

-- at least one order is cancelled update orders flag
insert into orderdetail values (10000, 1236, 'thing1', 9.95, 10, 1);
insert into orderdetail values (10001, 1236, 'thing2', 5.99, 10, 1);
insert into orderdetail values (10002, 1236, 'thing3', 1.99, 1, 0);

-- no orders are cancelled dupdate orders flag
insert into orderdetail values (10000, 1237, 'thing1', 9.95, 10, 0);
insert into orderdetail values (10001, 1237, 'thing2', 5.99, 10, 0);
insert into orderdetail values (10002, 1237, 'thing3', 1.99, 1, 0);

select orderid, max(iscancelled)
from orderdetail
group by orderid

--count detail items
update o
set isvalidorderflag = 1
from 
dbo.orders o
join 
(
    select  orderid
    , count(*) [total_lines]
    , sum(case when iscancelled = 1 then 1 else 0 end) [total]
    from orderdetail
    group by orderid) main on main.orderid = o.orderid
where 
    main.total_lines <> main.total
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a DML trigger on `OrderItems` table which will update `Order` status, doesn't matter how orderItems were changed.
Updated Version

```
create trigger tr_OrderItems
   on dbo.OrderItems after insert, update, delete
as
begin
   set nocount on
   declare @orders table(orderId int)
   insert @orders(orderid)
   select orderid from inserted
   union --distinct 
   select orderid from deleted
   --update orders
   ;with items as (--calculate counts
      select oi.orderid, count(*) itemCnt,
         count(case status when 'Cancelled' then 1 end) cancelledCnt
         --not 'Cancelled' produce null and not counted
      from dbo.OrderItems oi
           inner join @orders o on o.orderid = oi.orderid 
      group by oi.orderid
   )--CTE
   update orders 
      set flag = case when i.itemCnt = i.cancelledCnt then 'AllCancelled'
                      when i.cancelledCnt = 0 then 'NoneCancelled'
                      else 'SomeCancelled' end
   from orders o
        inner join items i on o.orderid = i.orderid
end
```

Comment: This line ` select @orderId=orderId from inserted --insert or u` is dangerous. It assumes that any INSERT or UPDATE action will affect only one row / OrderID

Comment: Insert / update / delete may affect many rows in `OrderItems` but there are little chances that they belong to different `Order`s.